# Split the String with comma and Star

Tags: java, string

Hi i am developing the android application now getting the String like under. I want to split my string with comma and with the Star is well.

The String Is : `kushal,naren,dhrumil,naren.zala@gmail.com,*Bcc:kushal.3106@gmail.com`

And What I want is :

> kushal,naren,dhrumil in String str1
>
> naren.zala@gmail.com in str2
>
> kushal.3106@gmail.com in str3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    String str = "aaa,bbb*ccc";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("[,*]")));
```

Comment: i have to display the s;it string in different text view. So how can i do so.

Comment: I am sorry, @Kushal Shah, I did not understand what do you exactly want. If your problem is still relevant could you plz ask separate question?

Comment: Actually i want aaa in some other string bbb in other String and ccc in other String.